# How do I effectively search across encrypted fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1, Ransack and attr_encrypted. I have sensitive data being stored in my database and I want to protect it using the gem attr_encrypted.

As I expected, I got zero results when searching encrypted test data with Ransack.

I tried the following solution to but it didn't seem to work for me. I was under the impression that the load function was used to return the decrypted value.

ReportsController

```
def index
  @report_list = Report.all.load
  @q = @report_list.search(params[:q])
  @reports = @q.result(distinct: true).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Has anyone had any experience searching across encrypted data and could help me generate a working solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load will cause the Active Record Collection to execute a query and retrieve the results matching your query (in addition to running after_create call backs which I believe is where the decrypt you were expecting is happening).

```
def index
  #returns all records in DB
  @report_list = Report.all.load


  #I'm surprised these aren't throwing undefined method search of Array (or something similar)
  @q = @report_list.search(params[:q])
  @reports = @q.result(distinct: true).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

I would like to precede this with, I normally do this thing manually and am not familiar with attr_encrypted or Ransack, but I believe these concepts are general enough they could be applied to any setup.  So, as to your question, 2 possibilities.

If your ok searching for exact values:

```
Model.where(encrypted_field: encrypt(params[:value])).first
```

where encrypt is a method that encrypts and returns the passed string.

Secondly (and painfully)

```
Model.all.delete_if{|m| !m.encrypted_field.include?(params[:value]) }
```

This will literally pull, decrypt, and scan every entry in your database.

I would highly recommend not doing this, but you need to do what you need to do.

If you absolutely need to have the information encrypted but still need to be able to do searches like this.  I would highly recommend adding tags of some sort to your model.  This would allow you to remove sensitive information but still search by some attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I never really thought about encrypting my search value. However I think I am leaning towards the tag feature, it may be better suited for my particular application.